# Why is the first argument of child's constructor being used in parent's constructer when inheriting `bitstring.BitArray`?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, bitstring

I want my class to inherit the `BitArray` class but I'm running into a problem in the constructors. I have several positional and keyword arguments I want to use in the child but the first positional argument is always used in the parent for some reason. Does anybody know why this is and how to fix it?

Example Code:

```
from bitstring import BitArray

class MyClass(BitArray):
    def __init__(self, var1, kwvar1=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.var1=var1
        self.kwvar1=kwvar1


a = MyClass('0xff', kwvar1="myvar")
print(a.b) # this should be empty
print(a.var1)
print(a.kwvar1)
```

Output:

```
11111111
0xff
myvar
```

The output of `a.b` should be empty since I didn't pass any extra arguments that would have been passed to `super().__init__()`, but instead it is a BitArray of ones. Furthermore, if I **do** give `MyClass` extra arguments, then I get a key error. For instance, if I change the code above to :

```
a = MyClass('0xff','0x0f0f', kwvar1="myvar")
```

then I get a `KeyError`:

```
C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitstring.py", line 964, in __new__
    return _cache[auto]
           ~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: '0xff'
```

It seems to me that in this example `a.b` should return `00110011` since `'0x0f0f'` would normally be the first argument passed to `super().__init__()` right? What am I missing here?

Comment: I think instead of using inheritance you should compose.

Python is duck typed, what benefit is inheritance offering you?

Comment: I wanted to use inheritance because it was going to be more convenient. That is out the window now that I've run into this issue. I still want to know why this doesn't work though.

Comment: @Сергей Кох, FYI it's clear that the OP wants to customize the construction of the base class ```BitArray```. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the BitArray defines the [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). See [the implementation](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring/blob/bitstring-4.0.1/bitstring.py#L3455).

So, do like this.

```
from bitstring import BitArray

class MyClass(BitArray):
    def __init__(self, var1, *args, kwvar1=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.var1=var1
        self.kwvar1=kwvar1

    def __new__(cls, var1, *args, kwvar1=None, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

And don't forget to reorder `kwvar1` and `args` arguments.

Comment: If I was doing this, as I commented above, I think it would be  clearer to compose rather than inherit, and not make assumptions about the implementation of the base class.

Since the BitArray new and \_\_init\_\_ is being skipped, you may be breaking the base class. I would never do this in production.

Whatever traits the composed BitArray needs to expose to your application, make a mechanism to forward/delegate those.

Comment: @Warren P, it's unclear. This problem cannot be solved with a composition. What you are suggesting? Is it like defining a class like ```ContainerOfBitArray``` with an instance variable of type ```BitArray```? I bet the OP does not want this pattern.(I smell Java over-engineering practice from your words.) And in the above code, ```__new__()``` and ```__init__()``` of the base class ```BitArray``` are not skipped.

Comment: Depending on implementation details of the parent class is a bad code smell in every language.

Explicit is better than implicit, and clear behavioural definitions are better than implicit unclear ones.  Perhaps others who work in python feel differently but customizing a class's constructor and bypassing some or all of its initialization feels ugly and fragile, to me.  I would need to study the constructor and the entire parent class to be sure I was doing this safely.